# How to download virtual directory in blob storage using angular & node?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

As we know the fact that we still dont have support for downloading virtual directory in blob storage, can we download the blob one by one and zip them somehow? Is that possible? Download directory/subdirectory is very important for my application, I am just looking for the solution if some how we can make download directory/subdirectory work.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're specifically asking, but... blob storage, by design, isn't a file system, and has no such support for combining blobs into a zip for download. For that, you'd need to do this on your own (perhaps downloading specific blobs to a vm or Azure Function or anywhere else your app is running, and then performing any needed file manipulation such as combining via zip). Alternatively, you could use Azure Files instead of blob storage, which then provides you with directory support via SMB.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested in my environment

I created a virtual directory in my blob storage and added the blob files.

In my local, I created a folder with virtual directory name in the same folder where my .js file exists.

I used the below code to download the entire virtual directory to my local:

```
async function main() {
    var fs = require('fs');
    const { BlobServiceClient, StorageSharedKeyCredential } = require("@azure/storage-blob");
    const account = "storage-account-name";
    const accountKey = "storage-account-key"
    const sharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(account, accountKey);
    const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
        `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net`,
        sharedKeyCredential
    );
    const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient("container-name");
    let iter = containerClient.listBlobsByHierarchy("/", { prefix: "virtual-direcotry/" });
    for await (const item of iter) {
        const blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(`${item.name}`);
        const response = await blobClient.downloadToFile(`${item.name}`);
      }
}
main();
```

[image]

[image]